# VBA makro to create seperate files for every worksheet in excel workbook on mac - splitbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-mac

I would like to split an excel workbook into one file for each worksheet using VBA on mac.
I tried many different makro-codes I found in different forums but I never got them to work. Does anyone have a code that works for him? The best code I found so far was the following:

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xcsvFile As String
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    xcsvFile = CurDir & "/" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename: = xcsvFile, _
    FileFormat: = xlCSV, CreateBackup: = False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
End Sub
```

I found this code here:
https://github.com/hami-gitgud/Excel_split_to_csv/blob/master/VBA%20Code

I replaced the blackslash by "/" to adjust it for mac.
However it is still not perfect as I would like to save .xlsx to desktop.
Does anyone know how to get this done ?

P.s.
`curDir` does not work properly on mac.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/curdir-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `FileFormat: = xlCSV` with `FileFormat: = xlOpenXMLWorkbook` and give it the proper extension.

Comment: Thank you, this already helps a lot. Do you also know how to define the output directory on mac?

Comment: Ok apparently its not really possible on mac without interaction to grant permission:
https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/sandbox/